# Cannot resolve symbol "ConvertView"

Tags: android, expandablelistview, convertview

I'm following this tutorial to implement **Expandable ListView**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GD_U0-N3zUI&t=404s
I did everything same as in it, But:

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String title=(String)this.getGroup(i);
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent);

        }
        return null;
    }
```

I'm getting this error: **"Cannot resolve symbol convertView"**

Tried:
[image]

Comment: there is no convertView in argument. Change convertView to 'view' that is present in the getGroupView(...View view....) method.

Comment: Check Updated Question :)

Comment: Watch not R.id use R.layout.parent. in inflate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did everything same as in it

No you didn't. If you watch the video closely you will notice the parameter names are different in the video.

> I'm getting this error: "Cannot resolve symbol convertView"

That is because `convertView` is not defined in your code. (in the video it is).

You can fix it by either changing the parameter names:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

The key here (for your problem) is the third parameter `View convertView`.

The other option is to use the your variable name `view` everywhere `convertView` is used.

Update: the `inflate` function expects a layout resource id (e.g. R.layout.parent an a corresponding XML file should exist in the rea/layout folder) as the first parameter. You are passing an ID resource.

Comment: Check the Updated Question Please :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace your code with below:

```
    @Override public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
{ String title=(String)this.getGroup(i);
 if(convertView==null){ LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, null); } return convertView; }
```